# Re-order XML for HTML printing

Tags: python, html, xml, python-2.7, xslt

I'm using Python 2.7 to convert an XML response (from a REST call to Atlassian Fisheye) into an HTML table.

The XML data is conveniently presented in "row" elements, and also includes the relevant "headings".  And, right now, I can produce a great looking table, except that the header row is printed last, as the headings are specified at the end of the XML document.

What's the simplest way of making sure they're at the top?  Can I do this with XSLT or do I need to manipulate the XML document first before converting it to HTML?  If the latter, what's the easiest/neatest way to reorder the XML elements?

The code I'm using to convert the XML to HTML is:

```
from lxml import etree

def xml_to_html(text):
  source = etree.fromstring(text)

  xslt_doc = etree.parse("change-report.xslt")
  xslt_transformer = etree.XSLT(xslt_doc)

  output_doc = xslt_transformer(source)
  print(str(output_doc))
  output_doc.write("change-report.html", pretty_print=True)
```

The XSLT I'm using looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="headings">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="heading"/></tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="heading">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="item"/></tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input XML (returned by Fisheye's REST API) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tabularQueryResult>
  <row>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">167</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">trunk/build.gradle</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">ABC-1835 Include RPM building code</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">u4538</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">2018-03-13T11:43:15Z</item>
  </row>
  <row>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">166</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">trunk/settings.gradle</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">ABC-1863 Added new subproject.</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">a2345</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">2018-03-06T13:31:15Z</item>
  </row>
  <row>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">165</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">trunk/build.gradle</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">ABC-1826 Refactoring.</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">u4538</item>
    <item xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">2018-02-28T10:56:15Z</item>
  </row>
  <headings>
    <heading>csid</heading>
    <heading>path</heading>
    <heading>comment</heading>
    <heading>author</heading>
    <heading>date</heading>
  </headings>
</tabularQueryResult>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a template matching `tabularQueryResult` in your XSLT, which means the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) will apply. This will just select the child nodes of `tabularQueryResult` in document order. As `headings` is after `row` in the input XML, they come out last. (The fact you have a template matching `headings` before the template matching `rows` really makes no difference whatsoever).

To solve this, just add a template for `tabularQueryResult` and explicitly select the order you want.

```
<xsl:template match="tabularQueryResult">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="headings" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="row" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was so close to that solution, but was missing the fact that I needed to explicitly match that top-level element name, and didn't realise there were built-in template rules.